# Has Steven shown any signs of aging?

Tags: steven-universe

In "Steven's Birthday," in Season Two, we learn that Steven's growth has stagnated somewhat, presumably because of his Gem half. In fact, his appearance has changed little for several years (he's actually chronologically 14). Naturally, this causes him some worry (particularly regarding his relationship with Connie).

However, at the end of the episode, he discovers a single facial hair, indicating that he *is* maturing somewhat.

It's been about two years in-universe since that episode, I think. Has Steven grown at all taller since then? Has his appearance changed with age in any other way?

Comment: Not in any way that's been remarked on, thus making this impossible to answer yet. The models are inconsistent.

Comment: @Axelord - Awwww. Are you sure that there hasn't been anything? That they devoted basically a whole episode to it definitely made it seem like more than a one-off joke. What do you mean about the models?

Comment: As a side note, what about Lars, Sadie, Connie, Onion etc.? They are all human (well, Onion might not be).

Comment: The models are inconsistently depicted, both due to the work being done by two different studios and due to general changes in style over time.  Steven will appear taller or shorter in different episodes without this being a change in-universe.  Aging hasn't really come up since that episode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steven Universe: the Movie will be released in September 2, 2019. The movie is set two years after the season 5 finale.

Steven has grown quite noticeably in the movie. He is now almost as tall as Greg, and is only one head shorter than Pearl.

[image: Steven and Greg]

[image: Steven and the Crystal Gems]

Comment: And he's about the same height as Connie, though the quick scene in the commercials you see this in almost seems like a spoiler to post.

Answer (score 7):

In a recent episode he shaves (the shaving cream's name of "Big Boy's 1st Shaving Cream" indicates this might be his first time).  But he still only had the one hair from his birthday.

[image: Steven shaving his one facial hair]

Stevonnie has also recently been shown with meaningful amounts of stubble, to the point they opted to shave when fused for an extended period of time.  Earlier Stevonnie fusions did not have stubble.

[image: Stevonnie gets stubble]

It has been my personal impression that Steven has gotten a little less chubby over time.  He has been shown as being (superhumanly) strong, at times with it appearing that he's slightly muscular.

A relatively recent appearance:
[image: Steven being Sour Cream's roaide]

Versus a fairly early appearance (the episode where he first meets Connie, in particular):
[image: Steven meets Connie, in a sea bubble]

He seems thinner in the more recent incarnations.  But as mentioned in the comments his exact appearance tends to vary between episodes, at least in part because the show isn't always animated by the same people. So he can seem fatter or thinner, shorter or taller, from episode to episode.  Still, as I said, my impression is that over time he's gone from "chubby, probably even just fat" to more "husky, maybe a little chubby".

That said, the show's emphasis seems to be more on personal and emotional growth; there are lots of struggles with personal identity, and where they "belong", for Steven and other characters, in particular. Characters over time realize that Steven has grown much more confident, decisive, and leader-like with time. Garnet even has a minor crisis when she's having trouble seeing future events, only to eventually realize it's because she's still seeing Steven as a child who can't do things for himself, and as such she is trying to look into futures where he behaves that way, when he is in fact much more mature now and able to make decisions and handle tough situations on his own.  Once she realizes this, and starts looking to futures that more accurately reflect who he is, her crisis abates.